# Possible Angular attribute directive bug?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create an Angular directive which is just an HTML attribute (`my-directive`). This directive uses some input attributes (`text`, `length`).

```
<li my-directive text="first" length="6"></li>
```

Everything works nicely when I use it just once. But I'd like to use it multiple times, for list items:

```
<ul>
  <li my-directive text="first" length="elements[0].len"></li>
  <li my-directive text="second" length="elements[1].len"></li>
  <li my-directive text="third" length="elements[2].len"></li>
  <li my-directive text="fourth" length="elements[3].len"></li>
</ul>
```

This is when I experience a weird behaviour: Each list item displays the last item's attributes. I checked it, and the directive controllers receive the different values. Still, only the last one is displayed.

I'm pretty sure someone else bumped into this before, but I couldn't find anything related.

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/X4JhC7?p=preview)

**UPDATE:**

It looks like this issue can be solved using `ng-repeat`, but I'd rather not use that. And still it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It does look like a bug. Can you share the directive code so we can try and see if something is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I personally think it can be interpreted as a bug, but honestly is more like a consequence of how `bindToController` and directives work.

The problem can be described as a scope issue. Directives don't create an isolated scope by default, unless you tell it to do so. According to [angularjs docs for bindToController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) by using `bindToController` also doesn't create a scope by default so all your directive is doing by a logical accident, is binding your controller scope on the parent scope (i.e., myController). For example, if you add a `console.log(scope)` on a link function you will see that all scopes are the same for each directive.

```
  link: function (scope) { console.log(scope);}
```

However, regardless the fact that it can be way problematic to handle this without the knowledge of this behaviour, it can be done by creating an isolated scope like the following example and using a boolean version of `bindToController` feature.

```
  bindToController: true,
  scope: {
    text: '@text',
    length: '='
  }
```

Complete snippet:

```js
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'here';
      $scope.elements = [{
        len: 7
      }, {
        len: 13
      }, {
        len: 12
      }, {
        len: 35
      }, ]
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
          text: '@text',
          length: '='
        },
        controller: function() {
          var ctrl = this;
          return ctrl;
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: '{{ ctrl.text }} - {{ ctrl.length }}'
      }
    });

  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  {{ test }}
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li my-directive text="first" length="elements[0].len"></li>
    <li my-directive text="second" length="elements[1].len"></li>
    <li my-directive text="third" length="elements[2].len"></li>
    <li my-directive text="fourth" length="elements[3].len"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

use isolated scope for directive will solve the problem

http://plnkr.co/edit/pwfbShFYLPMHlSLf48ng?p=preview

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      bindToController: {
        // text: '@text',
        length: '='
      },
      scope: {},
      controller: function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        return ctrl;
      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      template: '{{ ctrl.text }} - {{ ctrl.length }}'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be one solution for this.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      {{ test }}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="elm in elements" my-directive text="{{elm.text}}" length="elm.len"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and in script.js

```
$scope.elements = [
         {
           text:'first',
           len: 7
         },
         {
           text:'second',
           len: 13
         },
         {
           text:'third',
           len: 12
         },
         {
           text:'fourth',
           len: 35
         },
      ]
```

Comment: You're right indeed, `ng-repeat` would solve this issue. However, I don't want to use it here.

Comment: Actually you woulg `ng-repeat` the `<li>` tag not the `<ul>` or the computed result would look like this : `<ul><li ...></li></ul><ul><li ....></li></ul>...` where what you want here is more `<ul><li ...></li><li ...></li>...</ul>`

Comment: @KiJéy I already edited and it still works fine with `ng-repeat` on `li` elements.

Comment: @fodma1 Then why not use it ? If you don't want to loop through all the elements, it's still easier to craft a sub-element in your controller and loop through that one or add a boolean field to every element and use a filter in the `ng-repeat`